# mongodb aggregation: How to return a the object with min/max instead of the value

Tags: mongodb

Say my document has a `date` field, and I want to get the first and last occuring documents in an aggregation.  Using `$group` and `$min` or `$max`, it's easy to get the dates themselves, e.g.:

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([
  { $group: {
      _id: 1, // for the example say I'm grouping them all ... 
      first: { $min: "$date" },
      result: { $push: { ... } } // ... and returning them all
  }}
])
```

This would return a result like:

```
{ _id: 1, first: ISODate(...), result: [...] }
```

But what I want isn't the first date, but rather *the result with the first date*.  How would I get at this using the pipeline?

I've been tinkering with using `$project` to scan the array afterwards for the object with the matching date, which seems like it could work, but I thought I'd see if there was a *proper* way to do this before I stumbled on an improper one.

Comment: `$first` operator might do it, replace $min with it

Comment: `$first` would work, but it would mean I'd need to sort them first in addition to the `$group` operations, which I was hoping to avoid.  Additionally, in the real use-case I'm actually returning more computed values than `first`, which would mean I'd have to sort multiple times.

Comment: I think $first can also take find order so you don't have to give an explicit sort. Though it doesn't make much sense and will produce random results each time

Comment: That's a good point about the indices.  And that the first value might be shared by multiple records.  I suppose if I did use sort and `$first` I could apply more conditions to the sort to keep the result consistent.

Comment: @Sammaye Your comments actually made me rethink what I want to do.  If you could post your suggestion to use sorting and `$first` I'll accept it.

Comment: heh, done; glad to have caused a brain wave :)

Comment: I was actually unwinding an embedded array earlier in the pipeline.  What I hadn't considered (and your comments made me realize) is that I really wanted to sort on those embedded docs, which would have caused problems.  Instead of an aggregate I'm just going to make another collection.  Thanks again.

Comment: Ok kool yea pre-aggregation is another awesome tool

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `$first` here to be able to get the first of a sorted set ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/first/#_S_first ):

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([
  { $group: {
      _id: 1, // for the example say I'm grouping them all ... 
      first: { $first: "$date" },
      result: { $push: { ... } } // ... and returning them all
  }}
])
```

This will also you to use indexes for sorts on the $group which increases performance.

Comment: so i need to get the set sorted in order to get an object with a min value...? big O(uch)

Comment: @HertzelGuinness This question was a long time ago and I have actually forgotten what the hell I was on about. This answer was specifically towards the OPs end, but sometimes it can be faster to sort and then get first than use $Min to get min

Comment: This may not work with a very large dataset causing the resulting grouped document to exceed the 16Mb limit