# Getting a complete object via $max in mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of objects that need to be grouped by `masterID` or `id` if `masterID` is absent. Of a group of objects with the same `masterID` I need to find the one with the highest `pos` attribute (`$max: "$pos"`). However, I struggle to get the complete object where `pos` is maximized, it seems via aggregation I can only get the `pos` attribute, but not the whole object. Here is the sample aggregation I use, lacking the `$ifNull` for `masterID`:

```
> db.tst.aggregate([{ "$group": { "_id": "$masterID", "pos": { "$max": "$pos" } } }])
```

Sample objects would be:

```
> db.tst.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("547d6bd28e47d05a9a492e2e"), "masterID" : "master", "pos" : "453", "id" : "hallo" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("547d6bda8e47d05a9a492e2f"), "masterID" : "master", "pos" : "147", "id" : "welt" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("547d6be68e47d05a9a492e30"), "masterID" : "master2", "pos" : "1", "id" : "welt" }
```

The wanted aggregation result is:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("547d6bd28e47d05a9a492e2e"), "masterID" : "master", "pos" : "453", "id" : "hallo" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("547d6be68e47d05a9a492e30"), "masterID" : "master2", "pos" : "1", "id" : "welt" }
```

Is there a way to achieve this result via aggregation, or do I need to use `$push` to obtain all grouped objects and implement the maximisation on `pos` in the Java code around the aggregation?

This question [mongodb aggregation: How to return a the object with min/max instead of the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653282/mongodb-aggregation-how-to-return-a-the-object-with-min-max-instead-of-the-valu) indicates that `$first` or `$last` should be used on the objects sorted by `pos`, but I fail to see how that returns the whole object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Start by sorting by `pos` descending. That way, the first document encountered for each `masterID` is the document with the highest `pos`. You can use `$$ROOT` to refer to the entire document currently being processed in the pipeline.

```
db.tst.aggregate([
    { "$sort" : { "pos" : -1 } },
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": { $ifNull: [ "$masterID", "$_id" ] },
        "max_doc" : { "$first" : "$$ROOT" }
    } }
])
```

Comment: I don't understand the `$$ROOT`. In `$$ROOT` there is a whole document after `$sort`? In this way you can do object ?

Comment: `$$ROOT` refers to the document currently being processed in the pipeline. See [http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT)

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood right, you could try this:

```
db.tst.aggregate([
    { "$sort" : { "pos" : -1 } },
    { 
    "$group": { 
        "_id": { $ifNull: [ "$masterID", "$id" ] },    
           "_Tempid":{$first:"$_id"},
           "masterID":{$first:{ $ifNull: [ "$masterID", "$id" ] }},
           "pos": { "$max": "$pos" },
           "id" : {$first:"$id"}

      }  
  },{
      $project:{
          _id:"$_Tempid",
          "masterID":1,
          "pos":1,
          id:1
      }
  }

])
```

result:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("547d6be68e47d05a9a492e30"),
            "masterID" : "master2",
            "pos" : "1",
            "id" : "welt"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("547d6bd28e47d05a9a492e2e"),
            "masterID" : "master",
            "pos" : "453",
            "id" : "hallo"
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: You need to sort by `pos` first, or the document from which the `$first` values will come is just the first doc in the group in natural order.